# CGColor not defined for the UIColor UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 0 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

application crash and i have this error in my Xcode console:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -CIColor not defined for the UIColor UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 0 1; need to first convert colorspace.
```

when I try to display the value of RGB color :

```
 var color:UIColor
 print("color \(color.CIColor.red)  \(color.CIColor.green)  \(color.CIColor.blue)")
```

Comment: That code does not compile. How/where is `color` initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `CIColor` doc:

> `var CIColor: CIColor { get }`
>
> The Core Image color associated with the receiver. (read-only) This
>   property throws an exception if the color object was not initialized
>   with a Core Image color.

Use `getRed` method to get RGB:

```
var color = UIColor.redColor()
var fRed: CGFloat = 0
var fGreen: CGFloat = 0
var fBlue: CGFloat = 0
var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
if color.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
    print("color \(fRed)  \(fGreen)  \(fBlue)")
} else {
    print("error: color could not be converted")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialising the *color* value to some default value should work:

```
var color = UIColor.white
```